# Two modules in one package.json file

Tags: npm

I am trying to create a plugin that is UI Framework independent. I cannot do any dynamic imports so I have decided to build it two times with rollup. But now I have the problem that I cannot import the different files separately.

How my structure looks:

```
- dist
    - quasar.js
    - vuetify.js
```

In my package.json I have `dist` as main. But when I try the following in my application I get an error:

```
import VueScanField from 'vue-scan-field/quasar'
```

The error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* vue-scan-field/quasar in ./src/boot/vue-scan-field.ts
```

There is probably something wrong with the `main` variable in my package.json. Thats why it is not recognizing `/quasar`. Anybody any idea?

I have tried subpaths exports but with the same result. My config looked like this:

```
  "exports": {
    "./quasar": "./dist/quasar.js",
    "./vuetify": "./dist/vuetify.js"
  },
```

But I still get the same error

Comment: I've added a complete example to show how you can use `exports` field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try filling `exports` field in `package.json`. Documentation addresses the exact use case you describe:

> ### Subpath exports
>
> When using the "exports" field, custom subpaths can be defined along
> with the main entry point by treating the main entry point as the "."
> subpath:
>
> ```
> {
>   "main": "./main.js",
>   "exports": {
>     ".": "./main.js",
>     "./submodule": "./src/submodule.js"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Now only the defined subpath in "exports" can be imported by a
> consumer:
>
> ```
> import submodule from 'es-module-package/submodule';
> // Loads ./node_modules/es-module-package/src/submodule.js
> ```
>
> While other subpaths will error:
>
> ```
> import submodule from 'es-module-package/private-module.js';
> // Throws ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED
> ```

Further info:

- https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports
- https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/

## Demo scenario

Folder structure:

```
├── package // the package we want to distribute
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── submodule1.js
│   └── submodule2.js
├── main.js // consumer script
└── package.json
```

submodule contents:

```js
// ./package/submodule1.js
export default 'submodule1.js'

// ./package/submodule2.js
export default 'submodule2.js'
export const name = 'second submodule'
```

inside `./package/package.json`, I defined submodule exports for these files:

```json
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "type": "module", // enable ESM imports
    "exports": {
        "./a": "./submodule1.js",
        "./b": "./submodule2.js"
    }
}
```

then I installed the `./package` directory in consumer project using `npm install ./package` which added an entry in `./package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "consumer",
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "my-package": "file:package"
    }
}
```

Now, I can import submodules (both default and named exports) from `./main.js`:

```js
import a from 'my-package/a'
import b, {name as bName} from 'my-package/b'

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(bName);
```

which prints:

```
submodule1.js
submodule2.js
second submodule
```

I can go as far as to prevent importing the base package and only allowing submodules by explicitly setting root package export to `null` (or by simply omitting it altogether):

```json
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "main": "main.js",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        ".": null, // prevent importing root package
        "./a": "./submodule1.js",
        "./b": "./submodule2.js"
    }
}
```

which causes this code to throw error

```js
import mypackage from 'my-package'
```

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /path/to/demo/node_modules/my-package/package.json imported from /path/to/demo/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:337:9)
    ...
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:56:36) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Comment: Hi! It indeed looks exactly like what I want but unfortunately it gives me the same error. I edited the post

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I've added a sample to demonstrate the usage

Comment: I think it has something to do with typescript. Anyways `"type": "module"` made a big difference. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079 for the issue. Anyways I will accept this as the answer!

Comment: It's not supported in browser afaik.